# manipulating the contents of dictionaries inside dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I am receiving data from a radar on different contacts. each contact has a lat, lon, direction, range and time stamp. and each time hit on a contact will be ID'd such as 1,2,3 etc. for one contact this suggests a dictionary over time. therefore, my dictionary for one contact will look something like this:

```
{1:[data @ t1], 2:[data @ t2], 3:[data @ t3]}
```

And as time goes on the dictionary will fill up until ...But there will not be only one contact. there will be several, maybe many. this suggests a dictionary of dictionaries:

```
{'SSHornblower': {1:[data], 2:[data], 3:[data]},
 'Lustania': {1:[], 2:[], 3:[]},
 'Queen Mary': {1:[], 2:[], 3:[], 4:[]}}
```

It is not possible to know before hand how many contacts my radar will find, maybe 3 maybe 300. I cannot come up with names ahead of time for all the possible contacts and names for all the possible dictionaries. Therefore, I came up with the idea that once i nested a dictionary inside the larger dictionary, i could clear it and start over with the new contact. but when i do a clear after i nest one inside another, it clears everything inside the larger dictionary! Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: What code do you have so far? Can you also format your code/data. That block of text is an eyesore.

Comment: Do you need the O(1) access time of a dictionary?  If not, you could store your contacts in a list.  If you _do_ need a dictionary, then you'll need a system of assigning guaranteed-unique identifiers (probably integers --- don't assume the names are unique) to unknown contacts.  (Also, consider using a list or a [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) to store the radar "pings", since the obvious use of a bunch of timestamped data is to iterate it in chronological order... and maybe drop all pings older than _n_ seconds.)

Comment: Not sure I understand your problem. In particular, why are you thinking of clearing things. Can't you just add a new entry in your main dictionary when you encounter a new contact?

Answer (score 0):

For filling up nested dictionaries a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html) can be very useful.

Let's assume you have a function `radar()` that returns three values:

1. contact_name
2. contact_id
3. contact_data

Then the following would do the job:

```
from collections import defaultdict

store = defaultdict(dict)

while True:
    contact_name, contact_id, contact_data = radar()
    store[contact_name][contact_id] = contact_data
```

So even if there will be a new contact_name that is not yet present in the `store`, the magic of defaultdict will make sure that an empty nested dict will already be there when you access the `store` with the new key . Therefore `store[new_contact_name][new_contact_id] = new_contact_data` will work.